# Conservative procedures for avoiding intermarriage?

Tags: marriage, heterodox, intermarriage, conservative-judaism

Conservative rabbis are prohibited from performing intermarriages (e.g., 
http://www.rabbinicalassembly.org/sites/default/files/public/ethical_guidelines/Code%20of%20conduct-2011-public.pdf).

Is there a required, recommended, or standard procedure for a C rabbi to follow to assure that both parties of a prospective marriage are Jewish?

(Assume the rabbi in question has some passing acquaintance with the couple but no longstanding relationship with or detailed knowledge of the families.)

Comment: doubtful but best way to find out would be to ask them directly

Comment: @Dude   Is there a way to do that on the web?

Comment: You could try tweeting @[RabbiAssembly](//twitter.com/RabbiAssembly).

Comment: @YehudaW http://www.uscj.org/Aboutus/OurStructure/OurStaff.aspx

Comment: @Dude   Few of the people on this page are rabbis. Probably I could find a list of the members of the Law Committee, but they may respond in a bureaucratic fashion, provinding no information and slowly at that.  I was hoping that people on MY might have some informed insights into this question and provide some quick, informative responses.

Answer (score 5):

I can offer you one anecdotal piece of evidence. My wife and I were married by a Conservative rabbi in a town we had lived in for only a few years. He was satisfied of my wife's status by her conversion certificate from the Bet Din. For me, it was an interview. He had to rely on my telling of my family history for my status. I know he wished for something more documentary but he accepted my word that I am Jewish in the end.

As I said just one rabbi in one town.